# I am trying to create a VBA macro that duplicates a worksheet and then copies data in the worksheet to a new column

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first time posting on stack overflow, so any feedback is appreciated.

Right now I am trying to program a macro that does the following:

1. Duplicates current worksheet and moves new sheet to beginning of workbook (new sheet is also named by user via input screen)
2. Copies data in Column D to Column E based on 3 criteria in Columns A-C

I've coded Step 1, but Step 2 is where I am having trouble. I need to copy data from one location on the worksheet to another based on criteria. Below is an example of something what I'm trying to do

Example for Step 2 Macro:

[image: Example for Step 2 Macro]

Basically, I want it to copy the "Day's Sales" to the "Previous Day's Sales" in the new worksheet according to each of the 3 criteria (Name, Country, Product) in case anything changes and to make sure the values are being copied correctly.

Please let me know if any other information needs to be provided!

FYI here is the code I already have for Step 1:

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()

Dim newName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    newName = InputBox("Enter the date for the new worksheet")

    If newName <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited in my current code

Comment: Will the "3" boxes that make up your conditions always be unique? As in, will there ever be a possibility that two "George, USA, Fish" may be on the list?

Comment: No, there will always be at least one different condition. There wouldn't ever be 2 George, USA, Fish's. Although there might be a George, USA, Cattle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MoveOver()

'create variables
Dim lastRow As Long

'find lastRow
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'change i to whatever your starting row is. Cells(i, #), the # indicates the column index
For i = 2 To lastRow
Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 4)
Cells(i, 4).Value = 0
Next i 'new loop starts

End Sub
```

Having a closer look it seems like you just want to move today's sales data to the previous day, and then clear out "today". The code above should get you going.

Edit: Changed Cells().Clear to .Value and set to 0 to preserve formatting.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, thank you. However, it seems to completely delete all contents in the original cells. How would I change it so that it only erases the values and not formatting? Also, how would I stop the macro from deleting everything down the column. Specifically, what if I only wanted the macro to go until row 10? Thanks.

Comment: @ashultz95 - Try the updated code. Please mark answered if correct :)

Comment: This worked for changing the cell values to 0, but what should I do if i want the loop to stop at a specific row?

Comment: @ashultz95 In my `For` loop, `For i=1 to lastRow`, you would change the variable `lastRow` to whatever number row you'd like to stop on. Ex, `For i=1 to 5`.

Comment: @ashultz95 good to hear. you're welcome.  I'd recommend you go through some tutorials on loops in VBA. This might be helpful, https://trumpexcel.com/vba-loops/

Answer (score 0):

Please test the next code, also. It works fast (in memory, using arrays) for a big range:

```
Sub testMoveData()
  Dim shA As Worksheet, newSh As Worksheet, arrA As Variant, ArrFin As Variant
  Dim i As Long, newName As String
    Set shA = ActiveSheet
    arrA = shA.Range("A1:E" & shA.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value
    ReDim ArrFin(1 To UBound(arrA, 1), 1 To 5)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrA, 1)
        If i = 1 Then
            ArrFin(i, 1) = arrA(i, 1): ArrFin(i, 2) = arrA(i, 2): ArrFin(i, 3) = arrA(i, 3)
            ArrFin(i, 4) = arrA(i, 4): ArrFin(i, 5) = arrA(i, 5)
        Else
            ArrFin(i, 1) = arrA(i, 1): ArrFin(i, 2) = arrA(i, 2): ArrFin(i, 3) = arrA(i, 3)
            ArrFin(i, 5) = arrA(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    newName = InputBox("Enter the date for the new worksheet", "New sheet name setting")
    If newName = "" Then MsgBox "No sheet name allocated": Exit Sub
    Set newSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
      newSh.Name = newName
      With newSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ArrFin, 1), UBound(ArrFin, 2))
        .Value = ArrFin
        'A little formatting on the new sheet:
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
      End With
      With newSh.Range(newSh.Cells(1, 1), newSh.Cells(1, UBound(ArrFin, 2)))
        .Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
      End With
End Sub
```